# Load local pdf file in flutter webview

Tags: android, flutter

I have a pdf file in the cache which needs to be loaded in webview.

The code works fine in iOs but android shows a blank screen.

`@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<File>(
        future: pdfFile,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print(snapshot.data.path);
            return Container(
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl: 'file://${snapshot.data.path}',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              child: const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }`

Any help with this would be appreciable.